# how to share url + parameter using addthis social plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, addthis

how to share url + parameter using addthis social plugin?
I had read the addthis api, But I can not find whey to add my parameters.
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var addthis_config = {
        // I want to share link as this url + my_defined_paramater, how to set?
        url: location.href+'refer_id=1900'  //not correct
    };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#username=addthis"></script>
    <!-- AddThis Button END -->
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using jQuery too would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may need an ampersand in your url. Everything else looks fine from what the API docs show.

```
var addthis_config = {
    // I want to share link as this url + my_defined_paramater, how to set?
    url: location.href+'&refer_id=1900'
                     //^^^
};
```

I found some items in the support section. Hopefully this will help.

[Support page](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381242-url-title#.UWOgppNTDTo)

Basically, it says you can add an attribute called `addthis:url` to set a custom URL. Since you need the current page, you'll have to update it with JavaScript's `setAttribute()` method.

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style" id="addthis_container">
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
    <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var addThisCont = document.getElementById("addthis_container");
    var curUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.href;
    var withGetVariable = curUrl + "?refer_id=1900";
    addThisCont.setAttribute("addthis:url", withGetVariable);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#username=addthis"></script>
```

Comment: no, even add & ,the shared url sended to facebook is still no my prameter

Comment: @linjuming, I added some stuff, hopefully that will help

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code:

```
    addthis_share = {
     url_transforms : {
         add: {
             oReferrer: LoggedOfficeGuid
              }
         } 
     }
```

Comment: Give little bit explanation to your code. It makes your answer useful.